# If someone says,"women in shapeless cotton dresses", does he means the women are wearing ugly dresses?

Tags: meaning

> Women in shapeless cotton dresses

What does “shapeless” most probably mean here?

Does it mean "ordinary", or "bad-looking", or "without attractive design"?

Comment: Anybody help me?

Comment: Chill out, dennylv. For folks in the US it was the middle of the night when you asked this, and the crack of dawn for those in Europe. That's most of our answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where an [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shapeless+dress%22&tbm=isch) might be the best way to get a sense of the word if you don't understand it from the [definition and example sentence](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+shapeless).

This is an example of a shapeless dress:

[image]

The key feature is that it doesn't [taper](http://www.ldoceonline.com/Clothes+and+Fashion-topic/tapered) to follow any [contour](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contour) of the person wearing it.

“Shapeless” is the opposite of “[form-fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form-fitting_garment)”. Both are words that describe how closely a garment is tailored to fit a certain form. These are useful terms, because simply saying “tight” or “loose” could be interpreted as referring to the relative sizes of the person and the garment and not necessarily describe the garment's design.

---

Since it is generally considered a matter of prowess for a tailor to make person-shaped clothing, an author might use this word to call attention to the garment wearer's poverty and a resultantly [underwrought](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/underwrought) wardrobe, but people wearing “shapeless dresses” might also be seen as more practical or less interested in displaying the shape of their bodies for any number of reasons.

As always, count on context to give you a sense of what a word might add to overall meaning, especially in cases where subjective valuations like “*bad*-looking” or “*attractive* design” are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Men tend to find the shape of a woman appealing, the "hourglass" shape. A "shapeless" dress is one that conceals this shape, that hangs down straight on the sides so that the woman simply looks like a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

It's an emotive word used by people who believe that the purpose of clothes are for stimulation and titillation of (by assumption) men, who like women to be objects for their enjoyment.